# Sketch mangling Illustrator vector file: how to fix?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, sketch-app, file-format, file-conversion

[image: correct image]

I purchased the vector file above and when I open it in Illustrator, it looks just as expected.

However, when I open it in Sketch, it looks completely different (see below). I get the same result if instead use Illustrator to export in various formats (EPS, SVG) and open that file in Sketch (I've also tried copy pasting from Illustrator). Sketch just doesn't seem to be able to understand the file.

Is there anything I can do to use this file in Sketch?

[image: broken image]

Comment: You may want tos tart by removing the gradients

Comment: Check if you have the last Sketch-app version installed, you should also include it in your question.

Comment: Yes, it's the latest. (version 52.6)

Comment: The way Sketch and Illustrator work with vectors are different enough, that sometimes you run into situations like yours.  

That said, could you post a few screenshots of not just the Sketch Canvas, but also the Layers panel?

Typically, you'll see lots of masks with no styling, and then layers above it that have fills.

Sometimes it's a matter of manually digging through the layers until you can figure out how to get the right visibility  

A screenshot of the Layer list will help with that!

Comment: Sure, here's the top level structure: https://i.imgur.com/svD7FWG.png

Comment: Ah sorry David - should’ve been more specific. A screenshot of the layer list within Sketch, with everything expanded (just in case there are lots of nested groups and combined paths)

Comment: We recently release a converter which will allow you to seamlessly convert from illustrator to Sketch, you can check it out here: https://xd2sketch.com/converter/ai-to-sketch